# How can I evaluate a math expression containing constants?

Tags: php, string, expression, constants

How can I utilize a string in PHP as a PHP value?

Here's the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$reporting_val = "E_ALL";  //Could also look like this "E_ALL ^ E_WARNING"
error_reporting($reporting_val);
```

I want to use the string `E_ALL` as constant for `error_reporting()`.

I know it is possible to pass a string to a variable name in PHP as such:

```
${$reporting_val} = true;
```

Is there a way to use that string containing the constant as actual constant for `error_reporting()`?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Please check the question before marking as duplicate.
PHP error_reporting treats it's values differently than subjected duplicate question.

Comment: If I were to set $reporting_val = "E_ALL ^ E_WARNING"; there will be issues. Applies as well for setting the var to 0.

Comment: Well if you also want to parse operations as well, then you want to convert all constants and parse the math expression with all bit- and math- operators.

Comment: @Izzy004 what's the helpfulness of such an approach? Most applications usually set the error reporting level during their bootstrap and never change it.

Comment: @axiac I'm trying to accomplish allowing the error reporting to be set from a custom config file. File is brought in by init and parsed. Long story short, I would like to define the error reporting from w/i in this file for convenience, as the current setup allows for more than one config per application. It is helpful to allow an efficient method to change such a parameter on the fly. Hope I have explained this clear. It is a complex application, and would be difficult to explain the entire infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

So since you want to use a math expression with [error constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) for [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) you have prepare your expression and evaluate it.

So for this we have 2 different parts here.

1. The class `mathExpression` to evaluate your math expression.
2. The function `convertErrorConstants()` which we use to convert all error constants, with the prefix `E_*`, to an integer.

The `mathExpression` class simply takes a math expression and removes everything except numbers, math- and bitoperators. Then it just calculates it and returns the result back.

The `convertErrorConstants()` function searches for all `E_*` with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and checks if there is a constant defined with that name. If yes we return the value from it with [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

#### Code

```
<?php

    class mathExpression {

        public $expression = NULL;


        public function __construct($expression = NULL){
            $this->expression = is_null($expression) ? NULL : $expression;
        }

        public function calculate($expression = NULL){

            $this->expression = !is_null($expression) ? $expression : $this->expression;

            if(is_null($this->expression))
                throw new Exception("No expression set");         

            $this->expression = str_replace([",", " "], [".", ""], $this->expression);
            $this->expression = preg_replace("/[^\d.+*%^|&<>\/()-]/", "", $this->expression);


            $result = $this->compute($this->expression);
            return $result;               

        }

        private function compute($input){
            $compute = create_function("", "return " . $input . ";");
            return 0 + $compute();
        }

        public function setExpression($expression){
            $this->expression = $expression;
        }

    }



    function convertErrorConstants($input){
        $output = preg_replace_callback("/(E_[a-zA-Z_]+)/", function($m){
            if(defined($m[1]))
                return constant($m[1]);
            return $m[0];
        }, $input);

        return $output;
    }


    $str = "E_ALL ^ E_WARNING";

    $str = convertErrorConstants($str);

    $exp = new mathExpression();
    $exp->setExpression($str);
    $result = $exp->calculate();

    var_dump($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
int(32765)  //E_ALL ^ E_WARNING -> 32767 ^ 2 -> 32765
```

```
//32767 ^ 2

//0111 1111 1111 1111 ^  //32767
//                 11    //    2
//----------------------
//0111 1111 1111 1100    = 32765
```

Comment: You my friend, are a genius. Thank you for taking the time out to help.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy to implement solutions.

### Solution #1

I think you don't need all the possible combinations of `E_*` constants. I would identify a handful of combinations that are to be used (f.e. `E_ALL`, `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`, `0` etc.) and define values to be used for these combinations in the configuration file.

```
$errorLevels = array(
    'all'         => E_ALL,
    'almost-all'  => E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE,
    'errors-only' => E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE | E_WARNING),
    // ...
    'nothing'     => 0,
);
```

In the configuration file use the keys of `$errorLevels`, in the code look them up in `$errorLevels` and find the value to pass to [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

### Solution #2

A more flexible option is to have two entries in the configuration file: one for the levels to include, another one for the levels to exclude (useful when `E_ALL` is in the list of included levels).

In the config file:

```
errorLevelsPlus=all
errorLevelsMinus=notice,warning
```

In the code:

```
// Put all the E_* error levels here
$errorLevels = array(
    'all'     => E_ALL,
    'error'   => E_ERROR,
    'warning' => E_WARNING,
    'notice'  => E_NOTICE,
    // ... put all the missing E_* values here
    'none'    => 0,
);
```

The "parsing" code:

```
// Read the configuration values (comma separated strings)
$levelsPlus  = get_config('errorLevelsPlus');
$levelsMinus = get_config('errorLevelsMinus');

// Compute the combination
$value = 0;
// Add the levels to include
foreach (explode(',', $levelsPlus) as $level) {
    if (isset($errorLevels[$level])) {
        $value |= $errorLevels[$level];
    }
}
// Subtract the levels to exclude
foreach (explode(',', $levelsMinus) as $level) {
    if (isset($errorLevels[$level])) {
        $value &= ~$errorLevels[$level];
    }
}
```

You need to add the handling of configuration errors (when you misspell a word in the config file, f.e. and `$errorLevels[$level]` is not set).